# How can push my can light back up into the ceiling?

Tags: recessed-lighting

I can’t manage to push this can light back into the ceiling. I think it’s getting caught in the metal frame/lip above but no matter how hard I push it won’t break through. Any tips?

[image: can light]

Additional photos of can and ceiling recess: https://imgur.com/a/iW9Vw17

Comment: usually there are 3 sprig loaded legs that you have to push in

Comment: I can’t seem to find them. Photos of the can and ceiling: https://imgur.com/a/iW9Vw17

Comment: Remove the light from the can, and add a picture of the inside of the can. The legs might be there but broken or bent out.

Comment: I can't see well enough on your pictures, but it kind of looks like there are catches on the side of the can that might line up with three vertical risers in the ceiling mount. It may be you have to push the can up and twist into position to hold it.

Comment: It's also possible something has gotten out of shape and is causing interference.  Try rotating as you push it up.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I tried turning but it’s very hard to turn more than a few inches. It’s getting caught on the side of the metal frame and I can’t get it past it. The round frame looks bent a bit but I can’t bend/hammer it back. Do I just find someone to come take a look at this point?

Comment: I just tried to do another can and it looks like it was installed from on top. I can push it up very easily but very difficult to pull it through the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

What type/model can us it then we can look up.

Looking at your one only picture I see a movable clip, that probably can be pushed in with screwdriver (one clip at the time at the time).

The lover clip on the pic

[image: lover clip]

Comment: Hi here’s a link to more photos including label: https://imgur.com/a/iW9Vw17. Elite model B6PLIC-26-E-AT-W-120:  https://electrical.regencysupply.com/elite-b6plic-26-e-at-w-120.html